# On the "min" operator:what is the official definition of number n = min {a, b}

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, definition

The "min" operator often appears in delta - epsilon limit proofs.

What I can find while looking at limit proofs examples is something like this:

- the teacher says "if $\delta<a$ AND $\delta<b$, then the implication defining a limit holds".
- and after that, he adds: so lets choose $\delta = \min\{a, b\}$.

What I understand is that choosing $\delta = \min \{a, b\}$ guarantees that "$\delta < a$ AND $\delta < b$".

But I do not understand how the first guarantees the second.

I may be wrong in thinking that the first guarantees the second.

And ***my mistake may come from the fact I do not understand what means the min operator.***

This is why I asked this question as to the ***precise meaning of "min".***

Note : which key word should I enter on a search engine to get informations about this " min" operator? I guess" min" wouldn't work.

Comment: For finite non-empty sets $S\subset\mathbb R$, we define $\min S=\inf S$.

Comment: $2 × min(a,b) = (a + b - |a - b|)$

Comment: you could say $\min(a,b)=\frac12(|a+b|-|a-b|)$, so $\min(a,b)=b$ if $a\ge b$ and $a$ if $a<b$; cf. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#In_relation_to_sets)

Comment: You understand that $m=\min\{a,b\}$ is just the minimum (which means "least") of the two numbers $a$ and $b$, right? So you always have $m\leq a$ and $m\leq b$ (and at least one of these will actually be equality). So if $c<\min\{a,b\}$, then you always have both $c<m\leq a$ and $c<m\leq b$, in other words, both $c<a$ and $c<b$.

Comment: It will _never_ be true that "delta < a AND delta < b". What is guaranteed is that $\delta\le a$ and $\delta \le b$.

Comment: To get the strict inequality (which is usually the case in limit proofs ) take $\delta$ to be any positive number less than $\min(a, b) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual definition of $\operatorname{min}$ is as follows:
$$\operatorname{min}(x,y) =\begin{cases}x &\text{if }x\leq y \\y &\text{if } y\leq x\end{cases}$$
where the two cases cover every possibility (by totality of the order) and only overlap when $x=y$ (by antisymmetry). You show, by examining the two cases and using transitivity, that $\min(x,y)\leq x$ and $\min(x,y)\leq y$.

In fact, you can characterize $\min$ via this property as well: $\min(x,y)$ is an element of the set $\{x,y\}$ that is less than or equal to every other element. Antisymmetry of the order implies that this definition gives a at most one answer for any set and one may, via an inductive argument, show that such an element exists for every finite set.

One may also, a bit more sophisticatedly, note that $\min(x,y)$ is the greatest lower bound (a.k.a. the infimum) to the set $\{x,y\}$ meaning that it is a lower bound (i.e. is less or equal to both $x$ and $y$) and that every other lower bound is less than or equal to the minimum. This is sometimes handy to know when there's a possibility that infinite sets will show up - and this definition applies to some more general mathematical objects as well.

Note that you do *not* get that $\min(x,y) < x$ or $\min(x,y) < y$ in general - but this is just something to keep in mind - it's rarely a hard problem to fix while proving things about limits.